# How to install Qt version 5.9.5 in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04

Currently, Ubuntu 22.04 has Qt up to 5.15.3. I need to use a program that needs Qt 5.9.5 How could I degrade Qt to version 5.9.5 in Ubuntu 22.04?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Ubuntu's repository software (esp. many *universe* packages) are built for the Qt5 the system comes with; so *downgrading* it will cause *dependency hell* issues on your system. I'd suggest running a VM using an older release with the Qt5 version you need (*ideally keeping the VM offline*) as I only see *pitfalls* if you change the default Qt5 if your system has any software that uses Qt5.